# Use graphicscard from desktop for laptop gaming

Tags: laptop, gpu

Sounds like a bizar question so some clarification:

At home I have this nice setup: Desktop with q9550 and 560ti for gaming with dual monitor  running windows 7
For university I have a laptop: Clevo i7-2670QM with HD3000 running windows 8.1(preview)

Ideally I use the laptop CPU and operating system and desktop GPU.

Question: Can I use my laptops operating system and CPU and use the external GPU from the desktop PC?

I used to just use the SSD from the laptop in the desktop.
(I thought about that reading about shield (nvidia))

Comment: I think it is not possible without a PCIe link from the desktop to the laptop over say thunderbolt by which the GPU in the desktop could be exposed to the laptop.

Comment: What you want is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the laptops own monitor is not really possible as far as I can tell. However if you have an external monitor you can use a [ViDoc](http://www.villageinstruments.com/tiki-index.php?page=ViDock).